# there is an error when run npx command on window power shell

Tags: typescript, powershell, npx

whenever I try to run npx command on my window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQPpH.png)power shell it show me this error that "is not recognized as an internal or external command, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yngpb.png)operable program or batch file." what commands should i try to run it on my window power shell

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.